# text from ifstream is coming with "\0\0\0 in start

Tags: c#, c++, string, ifstream

Here is how I'm getting the text:

```
switch(lsel) {
    case 0:
        luafile = "lua/example.lua";
        break;
    case 1:
        luafile = "lua/example2.lua";
        break;
    }
ifstream f(luafile);
f >> noskipws;  //don't want to skip spaces !
vector<unsigned char> v(
    (istream_iterator<unsigned char>(f))
    , (istream_iterator<unsigned char>()));
LBytes lexing = LBytes(bytes, 2);
lexing += lselect;
lexing += LBytes(v.data(), v.size());
//f.close();
return lexing;
```

then I'm processing it in C#:

```
int docnumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(Core.ncon.ArrayRead, 2);
Log(docnumber.ToString());
char[] valx = new char[Core.ncon.ArrayReadSize - 2 - sizeof(int)];
Array.Copy(Core.ncon.ArrayRead, 2, valx, 0, Core.ncon.ArrayReadSize - 2 - sizeof(int));
Core.lua[docnumber] = new string(valx);
```

and put to RichTextBox

```
private void confListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (confListBox.SelectedIndex < 10) {
        string one = Core.lua[confListBox.SelectedIndex];
        this.luaTextBox.Text = one;
        }
```

Now one contains string :

```
"\0\0\0\0io.write(\"Please enter your name: \")\n-- name = io.read() -- read input from user\nname = \"someone\"\nprint (\"Hi \" .. name .. \", enjoy hacking with Lu"
```

and Text will be `""`

Where is this `\0\0\0\0` stuff coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are prepending your text with some stuff coming from a different source than the file:

```
LBytes lexing = LBytes(bytes, 2);
lexing += lselect;
lexing += LBytes(v.data(), v.size());
```

I would suspect the first two lines contributing the zeros.

Comment: ah sure mistake is in `Array.Copy(Core.ncon.ArrayRead, 2, valx, 0, Core.ncon.ArrayReadSize - 2 - sizeof(int));` it must be `Array.Copy(Core.ncon.ArrayRead, 2 + sizeof(int), valx, 0, Core.ncon.ArrayReadSize - 2 - sizeof(int));`